# Using SIMCOM SIM800 as a Bluetooth SPP Client

Tags: bluetooth, android

I just bought a SIM800 module for my Arduino project and I found that I supports Bluetooth too. I have already worked with HC-05 and my Android phone.

I tried to play with this module and able to connect it successfully with my Android mobile. I am able to make a call using it, accept a call, etc. But when I tried to send text data using it (in SPP mode), I ran into problem.

I have an app called Bluetooth Terminal in my mobile with which I use to communicate with my HC-05. But with SIM800, I can't connect.

I have read all the AT commands which are used to make a SPP connection. Here's a screenshot of the PuTTy terminal where I tried to make the connection:

[image: Screenshot of PuTTy terminal]

As you can see in the image, whenever I try to call

> AT+BTGETPROF=1

It never returns to me. I also tried the command with my Bluetooth visible in the mobile, but still no result.

Whenever I try to run the command or

> AT+BTCONNECT=1,4

My SIM800 goes into state 2 and I have to manually reset it.

Can someone please help me with this problem? I just want to use my SIM800 as a SPP client/server so that I can exchange text data with my Android APP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to make my SIM800 as server by making the request from the mobile, but now I can't send data from SIM800 and the data send by mobile is echoed back.

Comment: AT+BTGETPROF failed, so no sense making AT+BTCONNECT=1,<n> (where n should be SPP profile index on the list returned by AT+BTGETPROF). Make sure that SPP is listed first. Also did you get +BTPAIRING: message? If so answer with AT+BTPAIR=1,1

Comment: Yes I know that there is no sense making `AT+BTCONNECT`. Yes I got the `+BTPAIRING:` message when I make the request from my mobile, but then my SIM800 enters into **Server mode** because of which I can't use `AT+BTSPPGET` and `AT+BTSPPSEND`

Comment: In server mode, module shall received +BTCONNECTING: "...","SPP" message - reply with AT+BTACPT=1 (shall return OK) and  AT+BTSPPGET=0 (auto mode). Then you can do AT+BTSPPSEND. For client mode, isn't you module shall start the initiation?

Comment: For being in client mode, yes I should initiate, but the same problem occurs with me which I have posted in the image @Flanker. The server mode works well but whatever I send to SIM800, it is echoed back and I receive nothing at my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default i see that the Android handset i used did not have SPP profile enabled. You need to open a App which enables the SPP profile to be advertised. Then after that you can get that in AT+BTGETPROF list. I made a tutorial for this, Have a look here,

https://youtu.be/zdQb8r2xRK8

and

http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/215-sim800-series-bluetooth-at-commands